# java conversion library that can handle generic types?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm looking for a Java library for converting values that supports generic types. That is, if I have `Foo<T>`, then the library should support converting a `String` to `Foo<String>` or `Foo<Int>`.

Of course given a class, one cannot tell its generic component. My aim is to populate a bean with string values. So the bean's properties can be examined for the generic type information.

Comment: How would the library know how to create a Foo?

Comment: Usually such things are done by allowing registration of custom converters that declare what they can convert.

Comment: There will be no safe way for the library to cast the result to a Foo<String>. The converters will have any generics they carry erased, so the library won't know which converter supports a given value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a skeleton of a solution:

```
public interface Converter {
    boolean canConvert(Class<?> sourceCls, Type targetType);

    Object convert(Object source, Class<?> sourceClass, Type targetType) throws CannotConvertException;
}
```

Note the source type is a `Class`, but the target is a `Type`. If it is a `Class`, then code can be delegated to one of the existing libraries. If `targetType` is a `ParameterizedType`, then you can get the type arguments (classes) from it, then the standard libraries can be used to convert to them.

To use:

- for fields: `Type targetType = field.getGenericType()`
- for setter methods: `Type targetType = method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, there isn't such a library.

Further, I don't believe it would be possible to create one.

Comment: Indeed, there isn't one. But I created my own utility class to do this. Wasn't very difficult. The trick is to use 'Type' as an argument to the converter and not 'Class'